# Excel VBA Insert/delete Row in Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Workbook for Inventory tracking and can't seem to make it work just as I need it. I have a Master Sheet with the Product and then Multiple Sheets for Warehouse locations. I would like to be able to add a new row in my master sheet and update the other sheets with the new product. I tried to write a VB Script to copy the part number from master to warehouse main and then populate the list with vlookup. I chose this approach so that when I change the description in master it would update all the sheets. I can't seem to be able to write a VB script that inserts a row where I want it to and do the same in my other sheets.

Here is an example:

[image]

Code I used to add rows from Master to Sub-sheet:

```
     Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For a = 1 To 10 
            Sheets("Master").Rows(a).Copy
            Sheets("VBtest").Rows(a).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Next a
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End Sub
```

Problem is it removes all my stock information. Just trying to add blank row and copy part number in first cell of row doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Is that example of how you want it to be, or how it looks with your code? Please post your code so we can take a look.

Comment: just link "Warehouse Main" and "Warehouse Remote" sheets cells content to those of corresponding  "Master" ones with such a plain formula as `='Master '!A2` to be written in ranges A2:F1000 (or whatever the maximum row size you need)

Comment: This works until i add a new row in master, the extra columns in sub-sheets remain but A:F get updated. The description for the items will change with your approach but it will not move the stock information down to match old description.

Answer (score 0):

add in "Master" sheet code pane the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Range("A" & Target.row & ":F" & UsedRange.Rows(UsedRange.Rows.count).row)
        Worksheets("Warehouse Main").Range(.Address).Value = .Value
        Worksheets("Warehouse Remote").Range(.Address).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ryan, did you get through it?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This works excellent on the items itself, but my stock information doesnt move a row down. If i extend the range to row I my Stock information on and below the row inserted disappears.

Comment: Any ideas user3598756? Thanks in advance.